# Listview items appear under tab in tabview

Tags: android, android-widget

When this displays the first two rows of the listview appear under the tabs, the Mercury, and Venus planets.  How do I get the tabs to occupy the top and the listview rows to start after the tabs?

***tablistmenu.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="" />
        </FrameLayout>

     </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<ListView 
android:id="@+id/lstMain" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
   </TabHost>
```

***tablistmenu.java:***

```
public class tablistmenu extends TabActivity {




    private ListView mainListView ;  
      private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;


       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

         setContentView(R.layout.tablistmenu);




          TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();

          mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("Contacts", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.contact_32)).setContent(R.id.textview1));
          mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("Credit Cards", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.credit_card_32)).setContent(R.id.textview2));
          mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("Notes/Misc", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.notes_32)).setContent(R.id.textview3));
          mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test4").setIndicator("Websites", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.globe_32)).setContent(R.id.textview4));

          mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);



             // Find the ListView resource.   
             mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.lstMain);  

             // Create and populate a List of planet names.  
             String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",  
                                               "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};    
             ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();  
             planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );  

             // Create ArrayAdapter using the planet list.  
            listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, planetList);  

             // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
             mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter ); 


          // End


       }


       }  
       }
```

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1):

See the [Hello Tab Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) tutorial for details, but basically it expects a LinearLayout under TabHost with a TabWidget and a FrameLayout.  Your contents would go under the FrameLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

I changed my code to the following and it worked perfectly.  Thanks Mayra!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="" />
                    <ListView 
android:id="@+id/lstMain" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
        </FrameLayout>
     </LinearLayout>

       </TabHost>
```